# Typescript with dynamic property names

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in typescript to have a property name generated dynamically by modifying another property name?

I'm trying to write some typings for a React higher order component that modifies the props passed to a wrapped component.  If you configure the hoc with a property name (e.g. `value`) it will also generate a property name from that (in this case, `defaultValue`).

A sample of partially working code on the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeACgJzmAOQEMBbaCAD2AgQBMBnKe4HFBNAPigF4oBvAFBRhUBKQgAuKLnzEyAgL4BuAQNCRpeMPWxa55KjQZMWbTj35CRAbQDSUNptniAulIBGcOABsIRBIqqbNQ4SEQAxtAwRN7e7hEA1rrOZFCU1HSMzKzsXIIiUAAUYFr0UjLayYTiHACUUgBucCi0gQJIAK4I4cAoiFAAFnDhVfpphpkmOZyF4YioaFLwyOijNQA0UEgISzFxiWtkdZYFcwjMUHMkYB3UtGO8AOS0EGEd3sCPUADUl-PoADoxGQAfRvChIoUAAybACMtQBwDgAFUwJAcNF6BBCrUfn8VmggeJQeDIfCVAVtoV8gUbGcFkSyG4oCwOhB1lZaVBrFcbnd9Mywt4sZyoAooERGBUdBV9HUVApVGcLtQLrwhuFqcDJFBHg0YmzHgpNoU4O4AFa47h5UXKnwQAHeOBoU0WgH67xszZm80Al5vD4ANQNEFqCrDAiAA).

Ideally, there would be no error when attempting to access `defaultValue`.

Comment: Your use-case sound similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323441/changing-property-name-in-typescript-mapped-type), but there are limitations. You could potentially consider putting all of the defaults in a `defaults` property instead, then you wouldn't need to change the name of the properties. Nesting the defaults under another property isn't exactly what you wanted, but it may suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer!  I couldn't find that sample during my searches.  We may indeed need to figure a different approach for the generic case or just make the other member names configurable so the user can specify them as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible back when you asked this question, but it is possible now with the introduction of [`Template Literal Types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) in typescript version 4.1.

We define a type that maps from a string literal "name" to its corresponding "defaultName".

```
type DefaultName<PropName extends string> = `default${Capitalize<PropName>}`
```

We declare the `Props` should have values for both the property and its default.

```
type Props<PropName extends string, Value = boolean> = {
    [K in PropName]: Value;
} & {
    [K in DefaultName<PropName>]: Value;
}
```

I moved the manipulation of the string into a separate function which asserts the correct return type for the string literal which it creates.  (Though technically, the hoc works without this assertion due to the `as Props<PropName>`).

```
function computeName<T extends string>(name: T): DefaultName<T> {
    const computedName = 'default' + name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
    // need to assert the return type here, otherwise it's just `string`
    return computedName as DefaultName<T>;
}
```

Your `hoc` is basically the same.  We still need to assert `as Props<PropName>` when calling `fn`, otherwise the object gets interpreted as `{ [x: string]: boolean; }`.

```
function hoc<PropName extends string>(config: Config<PropName>, fn: Callback<PropName>) {
    fn({
        [config.name]: true,
        [computeName(config.name)]: false
    } as Props<PropName>);
}
```

The magic happens in `test`, where now `obj` is known to have a property `obj.defaultValue`.  This fixes the error that you had before.

```
const test = hoc({ name: 'value' }, (obj) => {
    console.log(obj.value, obj.defaultValue); // no more errors
});
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KN7AnW)