# Typescript - substitute type property names from mapping

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes an object as a model and an object that represents a mapping. It returns an object with two properties: one representing the base model and one that represents the model with every property wrapped in another type. The mapping determines the keys of the returned object, and the mapping will always be

```js
type Mapping<Model> = {
    foo: string,
    bar: string
}
```

```js
function fooBar<M extends object, B extends Mapping>(model: M, mapping: B) {
    return {
        [mapping.foo]: model,
        [mapping.bar]: recursiveWrap(model) //this function would go through the model and wrap each property
    }
}
```

so calling this function like so:

```js
fooBar({ message: 'hello' }, { foo: 'thing', bar: 'thing$' })
```

should return a type something like this:

```js
type MyType = {
    thing: { message: string },
    thing$: WrappedType<{ message: string  }>
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to substitute property names from an object and still be type checked correctly.

I followed along with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323441/changing-property-name-in-typescript-mapped-type/45375646) but then the type of the returned properties were `{ message: string } | WrappedType<{ message: string }>`. Is there a way to pull this off without the result being a union type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems unlikely now (April 2020), but may be possible in the future.

See:

- [Typescript issue #12754: Augment Key during Type Mapping](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) - open issue, lots of use cases

  > I would like to open discussion to the prospect of augmenting property keys during mapping.
  >
  > For example: via arthimetic:
  >
  > ```js
  > type Changed<T> = 
  > {          
  >   [ P in keyof T ] + "Changed" ?: Function;
  > }
  > ```
- [Typescript issue #36623: Design Meeting Notes, 1/31/2020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36623) - "Augmenting Keys" discusses #12754

  > Can't necessarily say "yes", but probably not near-term. We should be focusing on speed.

Comment: ah bummer, dude. Thanks for the response!