# Type dynamically named properties

Tags: typescript

Here is my "normal" typing test:

```js
const prop1 = 'property1';
const prop2 = 'property2';
type Type1 = Record<typeof prop1, string> & Record<typeof prop2, number>;
let obj1: Type1;

console.log(obj1.property1 === '1') // ok 
console.log(obj1.property2 === 2) // ok
console.log(obj1.property1 === 1) // error : This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap. 
console.log(obj1.property2 === '2') // error : This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.
```

Here is my "dynamic" typing test; the only difference is the way I give property names:

```js
const prop1_ = prop1 + '_';
const prop2_ = prop2 + '_';

type Type2 = Record<typeof prop1_, string> & Record<typeof prop2_, number>;
let obj2: Type2;

console.log(obj2.property1_ === '1') // no error : ok
console.log(obj2.property2_ === 2) // no error : ok
console.log(obj2.property1_ === 1) // !!! missing error !!!
console.log(obj2.property2_ === '2') // !!! missing error !!!
```

Is there a way to make typescript manage my dynamically named property?

Comment: found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682391/4741914)

`
type Type2 = {[U in keyof Type1 & string as `${U}_`]: Type1[U]}
`

Answer (score 1):

[Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) enable the compiler to keep track of string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) concatenation, but it doesn't happen when you concatenate actual string literals using [the `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition#string_concatenation):

```
const ab = "a" + "b"
// const ab: string
```

So your `prop1_` and `prop2_` values are just of type `string`, and so `Type2` was just something like `Record<string, string> & Record<string, number>` which has no idea what your actual keys are.

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44905](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44905) asking for such support so that `"a" + "b"` would be of type `"ab"`. But who knows when or even if such a thing will be implemented.

---

For now, if you want to be able to get anything like this, you'll need to use an actual [template literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get template literal types, and furthermore you will need to hint the compiler that you care about the literal type via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const prop1_ = `${prop1}_` as const;
// const prop1_: "property1_"
const prop2_ = `${prop2}_` as const;
// const prop2_: "property2_"
```

There was an effort to make it so that you didn't need `as const`, but it broke too many things so they abandoned it (see [ms/TS#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588)).  Anyway, with that change, your `prop1_` and `prop2_` values now have literal types and the rest of your code works as expected.

---

Alternatively you could make a helper function which uses the `+` operator at runtime but whose call signature returns a template literal type concatenating the input types:

```
const concat = <T extends string, U extends string>(t: T, u: U) => (t + u) as `${T}${U}`
```

and it behaves similarly:

```
const prop1_ = concat(prop1, "_");
// const prop1_: "property1_"
const prop2_ = concat(prop2, "_");
// const prop2_: "property2_"
```

I'm not sure it's worth it to do that instead of template literal strings directly though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgIxgXhgIjmmBqdC0BQA9ETKJLIgFwzQBOAlmAOYyC8G4ER7BB50MADnRD8AjChgByQcICmdKAE8REgNw9wfafwBM4qUP5zF21QUWGYAFQWGxqAEozQdACYAeczJAAzAQZEANLRQjCwAfDAAZDCOzu6ePn7C2kFgAK4AtghyYWoELk4ANnB0MjCFMrAgCABWIjTWtnm8IBUAdIUgzAAU1XVtWkZKKMioEsoAlDAkMCAA1jDqkK0yHV29tSIDBkO6o6jaUzPzSxAraz19W4Pyw-swIkekckJ0MA0AFgwQZOAuDFAGOAYAB3BiFQrwQoguAKH6lKBpOhgSTeOCFCAyCS0JjAMpQD74mwyH4SdJZOTYuBgFySehMZjYj5wABuZTAIFmbLoxX4bUWLXanUum22slue1GkhMTxgLxAb0+31+NIBQJRYIhUJhcJgCKRKIkaIxWJxYDxMAJRMMpPJ2ToVJpdJCDKZrPZnJA3N5-O4p1gWhEAH1xAADAAkAG9AwBfIOh+A-XhQNQzZNJURBmhoG6KYOEdNabQh1AR6MGbRxhNwJMaFPEUiFitZ9C5hTFwhmYlWYl7GJOBXxYmJQNBoL08JRftxDzD3xFscwO05NQFYDFUrlSqzWraBq95oac7CjY1bRiwy3YMjMaTaakDlyuivd6zOanY-rPrntvFm8wQ57yXTl5UVN8PyFL9dwvIZr3uR4gNAiDVhPb8YIlEspQkGVEOfBVuDAOAMhJfg4AtABhcBgDgWBI24GAVT4chqNgVA3EsOUAA8oBkGkfgnZgggAVS4ni+OCUJmDCbooAaII0hoISpmQCIZJwGA0imGsYDLSwYyjISY1DAgGKbYQ4JVFjukDII0CDNAJjUBi0zrDNg2zNt8xMxiA2bcRmJo6yK1s+zHO8lyKAzYsPJ2DDOwYzwe0MPtYkHWdDBHfxFwEiJolS1x0q8edm1STJ7Vyby1w3MoKiqXd92SvJTKPSCRTPdC80w28JFlR9QNfE5muWVrTx-WLjC6gDepAvCwMGxjPzasbxU6-8EJmJChrOEa0N-SbsJ63DXm4GMgA)